# Deserialize an array inside a json object using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, json.net, xml-serialization, json-deserialization

I have a requirement where I have incoming json object of the following format:

```
{
   "CustomerList": {
       "Customer": [{
            "CustomerCode" : "C123",
            "CustomerName" : "Peter"
       },
       {
            "CustomerCode" : "C456",
            "CustomerName" : "John"
       }]
   }
}
```

And I have the my C# object of the following Format:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable = "false")]
public Customer[] CustomerList
{
   get; set;
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute()]
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerCode {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
}
```

During Deserialization using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(), I get the following error:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type Customer[], because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

On my side the limitation is that I cannot change the incoming JSON object and neither can I modify the C# object structure. So the ask is that, is there a way to map the Customer node in the incoming Json, to the CustomerList C# array directly, without needing to rename or change the structure of either?

Comment: `public Customer[] CustomerList` is this declared in some class! Can you share the code which does the deserialization?

Comment: yes CustomerList is declared in a class. I am not using any custom deserlization. I am just using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() in the Newtonsoft.Json Library

Comment: You need to share the code which does the deserialization. However simple it is. It will help us to see if there is an issue with the code or not and can suggest the solution accordingly. For now it looks like you are deserializing to wrong type but without looking at your code it's just an assumption

Comment: i am using a universal library, available here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json, so it should not be having any issues

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize the JSON object you need to create a similar C# class.

```
public class JsonObjectTest {
    [JsonPropertyName("CustomerList")]
    public Customer CustomerPreList {get;set;}
}

public class Customer {
    public List<CustomerObject> Customer {get;set;}
}

public class CustomerObject {

    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards you deserialize the JSON object:

```
CustomerList xmlData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObjectTest>(jsonObjectString).Select(data => 
    new CustomerList = data.CustomerPreList.toArray());
```

Unfortunately I could not ask you if you have a permission to create new classes (I need more points). If this is the case try AutoMapper to create a mapping policy for this specific case.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Is there no way to map  if the C# class has a different structure. For eg. by using [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CustomerList.Customer")][System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable = "false")]
public Customer[] CustomerList
{
   get; set;
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON you have shared, you need to have following class structure.

```
public class Customer    {
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; } 
    public string CustomerName { get; set; } 
}

public class CustomerList    {
    public List<Customer> Customer { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObject  {
    public CustomerList CustomerList { get; set; } 
}
```

and then you need to deserizalize the JSON as following.

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Here `jsonString` is the string variable which has the JSON string.

I hope you this will help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot (or do not want to) add new classes, the last two lines of GetCustomers() below should do what you want. Just assign it to the CustomerList property.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string? CustomerCode { get; set; }
        public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
    }


    public Customer[] GetCustomers()
    {
        string  json = @"{
                           'CustomerList':
                            {
                               'Customer': [{
                                    'CustomerCode' : 'C123',
                                    'CustomerName' : 'Peter'
                               },
                               {
                                    'CustomerCode' : 'C456',
                                    'CustomerName' : 'John'
                               }]
                           }
                        }";

        dynamic? contentObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        return (contentObj?.CustomerList.Customer.ToObject<IList<Customer>>())?.ToArray() ?? new List<Customer>().ToArray();
    }
```

I am working with .NET 6.0 so working with string? but for earlier versions of c# string should do the same. Play with the null handling as required.